# Проблема с проходом по массиву

Tags: php, sql

В общем есть запрос к БД, он возращет многомерный массив, потом я его провожу через функуию mysql_fetch_accos, он становится ассоциативным.

В общем мне надо собрать из него новый массив, но только уже что_бы были только id, а не еще куча, что я просил в запросе.

Проблема в том, что print_r($ids) = последнему значению

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($people); ++$i)
    {

   $ids[$i] = $people[$i]['id'];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $ids=array();
    $query="SELECT * FROM ...";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($item=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $ids[] = $item['id'];
    }
    print_r($ids);
```